# Multi-Tenancy without subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, multi-tenant

I watched Ryan Bates Railscast #388 regarding default scopes for multi-tenant apps.  He does it using subdomains.

For a few reasons, I'd like to be able to do it without subdomains. for example:

tenantA.example.com -->  example.com/tenantA

tenantB.example.com -->  example.com/tenantB

unfortunately, the only way, I've come up with to do this is to nest all of my resources inside of my tenant resource in my routes.rb file which has the sideeffect of requiring me to create deeper than preferred nested routes.

I'm wondering if there is a way to define a default route parent to avoid having to pass this along in every route helper.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem of loathing to include my scope in every single route helper call, thus I wrote the following Helper:

```
module OverrideRoutesHelper
  %w(foo foo_bar).each do |resource|
    module_eval <<-EOT, __FILE__, __LINE__ + 1
      def #{resource}_path(*args) do_dat_thang!("#{resource}", *args) || super end
      def #{resource}_url(*args) do_dat_thang!("#{resource}", *args) || super end
    EOT
  end

  def do_dat_thang!(resource, obj, *args)
    if obj.is_a?(Integer)
      model = resource.split('_')[0].classify.constantize
      obj = model.find(obj)
    end
    send("tenant_#{resource}_path", obj.tenant, obj, *args)
  end
end
```

What this does:

1. takes the helper resources that you supply in the first line (`foo`, `foo_bar`)
2. overrides the `_path` and `_url` helpers
3. calls `do_dat_thang!` which checks that the object passed in will respond to your tenant association call (if that is indeed the name of your association)
4. if it does, it calls `tenant_foo_path`, `tenant_foo_bar_path`, etc, with the arguments you originally passed, prepended by the tenant it retrieved from calling `tenant` on the first object argument..

so, for example:

```
foo_path(@foo)
=> tenant_foo_path(@foo.tenant, @foo)

foo_bar_url(@foo, @bar)
=> tenant_foo_bar_url(@foo.tenant, @foo, @bar)
```

Also, if you supply IDs instead..

```
foo_bar_path(1, 2)
=> tenant_foo_bar_path(Foo.find(1).tenant, Foo.find(1), 2)
```

Working a treat for me atm. It's kinda magical though, which isn't great.